# How to split column into multiple rows using Spark JavaRDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

Loading in the data:

```java
SparkConf sc= new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext JSC = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

JavaRDD<String> stringRDDVotes = JSC.textFile("HarryPotter.csv");
```

I currently have this table loaded into an RDD:

| ID | A | B | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 50 | Harry;Potter |

I want to convert it to the table below:

| ID | A | B | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 50 | Harry |
| 1 | 23 | 50 | Potter |

All the solutions I found use SparkSQL which I can't use, so how would I get this result using only things like `flatMap` and `mapToPair`.

Something like this maybe?

```java
flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(";")).iterator())
```

The code above produces this:

| ID | A | B | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 50 | Harry |
|  |  |  | Potter |

I know that in scala it can be done like this, but I don't know how to it with java:

```scala
val input: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq("1,23,50,Harry;Potter"))
val csv: RDD[Array[String]] = input.map(_.split(','))

val result = csv.flatMap { case Array(s1, s2, s3, s4) => s4.split(";").map(part => (s1, s2, s3, part)) }
```

Comment: your code should work, doesn't it work?

Comment: @mck It sorta works, the problem is that this code splits the Name column but does not write the ID, A and B with the new column. So it becomes `ID,A,B,Name(Harry)` and just `Name(Potter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is quite simple to convert from Scala to Java, you only need to use `map` to split each line by comma to get a `JavaRDD<String[]>`. Then using `flatMap`, for each row, split the last part of the array corresponding to `Name`, and using java streams, you can transform each element of the names list into a new list.

Here is a complete example:

```
JavaRDD<String> input = JSC.parallelize(
        Arrays.asList("1,23,50,Harry;Potter", "2,24,60,Hermione;Granger")
);

JavaRDD<String[]> result = input.map(line -> line.split(","))
        .flatMap(r -> {
            List<String> names = Arrays.asList(r[3].split(";"));

            String[][] values = names.stream()
                    .map(name -> new String[]{r[0], r[1], r[2], name})
                    .toArray(String[][]::new);

            return Arrays.asList(values).iterator();
        });

// print the result RDD
for (String[] line : result.collect()) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
// [1, 23, 50, Harry]
// [1, 23, 50, Potter]
// [2, 24, 60, Hermione]
// [2, 24, 60, Granger]
```

Comment: Thank you this works, only thing i'm having problems with now, is that i want to run a `.filter` on the RDD but that does not seem to work. So is there maybe another way to return instead of the `Arrays.asList(values).iterator();`?

Comment: @FlubberBeer you need to return iterator when using `flatMap` in java. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424107/1386551). What problem do you face with filter?

Comment: I want to check the amount of people with the name harry like this `result.filter( row -> row.toString().contains("Harry") ).count()` But this just returns 0

Comment: @FlubberBeer You can filter using `result.filter(r -> Arrays.asList(r).contains("Harry")).count()`. Or simpler : `result.filter(r -> r[3].equals("Harry")).count()`